# Cannot restart apache2 on Debian server - "Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server"

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, openssl, aptitude

Okay... I'm something of a beginner when it comes to servers, and I'm having some issues with restarting apache on my Debian web server.

I just ran the following:

```
aptitude install apache2 openssl
```

Immediately afterwards, I tried to restart apache and got the following error message:

```
IS-13902:/usr/local/apache2/modules# /etc/init.d/apache restart
httpd: Syntax error on line 55 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I ran ldd /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so and got the following output

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76f6000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb6d78000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb6d6f000)
libmysqlclient.so.16 => /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16 (0xb6a3d000)
libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0 (0xb6a19000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb6a04000)
libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62 (0xb69e5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb69bf000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb69bb000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1 (0xb69a1000)
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0xb6948000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0xb680f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb66b4000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb669b000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76f7000)
libidn.so.11 => not found
libssh2.so.1 => not found
libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb6652000)
libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb64ff000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0xb64bc000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0xb64ad000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb6499000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0xb6482000)
libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/libgnutls.so.26 (0xb63e5000)
libtasn1.so.3 => /usr/lib/libtasn1.so.3 (0xb63d5000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb63d0000)
libgcrypt.so.11 => /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11 (0xb6368000)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: IT looks like your apache2 init script is refering to an old or previously installed version of apache2 (probably from sources). You can easily tell that by the directory structure. _/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf_ actually should be located in _/etc/apache2/apache2.conf_ . Remove the old apache and then reinstall with --purge :)

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep libidn`?

Comment: The problem is that I didn't actually mean to install the new version of apache2. I was just trying to install openssl, but copied and pasted the whole command by accident. Is there any way to reverse this? I have a few key sites already running on this server, so I don't want to take it down for too long!

Comment: @quanta The output from that is
rc  libidn11
1.8+20080606-1           
GNU libidn library, implementation of IETF I

Comment: As already mentioned your best bet is to just upgrade Apache since you're down anyway. >Back up your site config(s) (.conf's).< Apt purge apache from system. Reinstall newest apache = `sudo apt install apache2` Convert your `.conf` files as needed. Place them in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Then activate them: `sudo a2ensite sitename.conf`. Start apache2 server and look for problems in your configs. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

Install `libidn11-dev` package:

```
# apt-get install libidn11-dev
```

and try again.

Comment: When I run ldd /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so I still get

    libssh2.so.1 => not found

Comment: I take it I should run  dpkg -l | grep libssh2 and then app-get install the relevant package?

Comment: Try this `apt-get install libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php`.

Comment: I got the following:
`apt-get install libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Couldn't find package libssh2-php`

Comment: You can remove the line what call that module on apache2.conf ( line 55 comment it ) or install libssh2 manually http://www.libssh2.org/ that the easy way. Also you can install it whit pecl comand, *pecl install ssh2*

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem in FreeBSD.
version of your `libidn` isn't camptiable with your PHP. You need to `apt-get update`, Then remove your `php modules` ,`php` itself and remove `mod_php`, Then install `php`, `mod_php` and their modules.
Don't foret to `php -m`